# How to persist static member in Shared preferences when it is about to be Garbage collected in Android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-sharedpreferences

I have a static member in Utility class, which is being accessed from most of my activities to store history info. I want to persist this static member when Utility class is about to be GCed. I tried below options.

> 1. finalize() method implementation:

I have overriden finalize() of the Utility class(I know it is not always guaranteed that finalize() will run) to persist static member in `Shared Preferences`.But `finalize()` not called at all!

> 2. Implementing onDestroy() in each activity to persist static member

I started implementing `onDestroy()` in all the activities which has access to this static member, when each activity is about to be destroyed, static member will be persisted in `SharedPreference`. This is working but writing to Shared preferences is happening very frequently causing unnecessary repetition of persists which I want to avoid.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: If you're worried about implementing life cycle events at all your activities, have a look at the [LightCycle](https://github.com/soundcloud/lightcycle) library. It has this usecase exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. Create a **ReferenceQueue** associated with your object type.
2. Create a **WeakReference** to your object and associating it with the **ReferenceQueue**.
3. Your **WeakReferenece** object will be added to the **ReferenceQueue** when it has no strong references (weakly reachable), so it's eligible for finalization.
4. You can create a Thread or a Service that **polls** the RefereneQueue for the reference object, if it's available, you can obtain it via the **WeakReference get()** method and save it to SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 10):

Don't start implementing bad custom practices. Considering the [documentation of `onPause()`](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29), this is the place where you should persist the data.

> This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a good place to do things like stop animations and other things that consume a noticeable amount of CPU in order to make the switch to the next activity as fast as possible, or to close resources that are exclusive access such as the camera.
>
> In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused processes to reclaim resources. Because of this, you should be sure that all of your state is saved by the time you return from this function. In general `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is used to save per-instance state in the activity and this method is used to store global persistent data (in content providers, files, etc.)

You don't have any guarantee, that for any approach you'll reach the point of storing the data.

Considering that your Utility class only has static methods and members and you'd never create an instance of it, so `finalize()` is never called. If you're using instances of the Utility class, just persist the storage where you'd expect it to be last reachable.

Considering to use `onDestroy()` isn't a good idea either. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) states this explicitly.

> *Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either `onPause()` or `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`, not here. This method is usually implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things around while the rest of its application is still running. There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.*

Answer (score 4):

> This is working but writing to Shared preferences is happening very frequently causing unnecessary repetition of persists which I want to avoid.

Just keep a `boolean` flag alongside the static member which indicates if the current data has already been persisted.

```
private static Object myStaticMember;
private static boolean saved = true;

public static changeStaticMember(...) {
    ...
    saved = false;
}

public static persistStaticMember {
    if(!saved){
        ...
        saved = true;
    }
}
```

---

Additional Note: If you want to avoid duplicated code in your activities, you can implement the `onDestroy` in a superclass and let all activities extend from that.

---

You should also consider using another lifecycle method. `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called. See [tynn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075670/4388512).

Answer (score 4):

Let say the target is saving that static member to SharedPreferences only when user stop using the app, if any activities are still showing, just keep that static member on RAM for fast access and not doing too much IO work.

You can try overriding method [onTrimMemory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTrimMemory(int)) in Application class, and check if the parameter `level` is larger than [ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) then you store that member to SharedPreferences.

It is: when all of your activities are not showing to user anymore (either go to background or totally destroyed) this callback will be triggered and that is a good time to release some mem-cache and store some history data into persistent storage.

In my project, I do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);

    if (level >= ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache();

        if (level >= ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
            // When our app is not visible anymore, start freeing up some cache and resources
            // that only need when UI is visible
            CurrentSession.getInstance(this).endSession();

            if (level >= ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND) {
                cacheManager.freeUpMemCache();
                cacheManager.flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all the question is: What is that object (it seems it is not a complex object because you store it in your Shared Preference) ?!?!

if we are talking about an object,this is what you should do:

just make a class and Extends it from Application.

```
public class MasterApplication extends Application {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
   }
}
```

After that define it in your manifest :

```
<application
    ...
    android:name=".MasterApplication"
    ... >
```

Now declare your variable in your application class :

```
public class MasterApplication extends Application {
   //HERE DECLARE YOUR VARIABLE
   public static int MY_INT=1;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
   }
}
```

now you have access to that variable from everywhere in your app.

> IMPORTANT NOTE : There is no need to be afraid of GC and memory leak !!!

As the application class is the session of your app and it is always active when your app is running or in background (Until time which the android kill your application)

Let's say we are talking about a method or class or object which needs a context and you are afraid of Memory leak as a persistent Context in memory. Don't be afraid again! you already done the job !

just in onCreate of your Application class call that object or function and pass this instead of Context!

This, refer to your application context and as i mention before, it's always in background!

> Saving in and reading from SharedPreference Scenario:

The most easy way is making a function in your application class again. do like this:

public class MasterApplication extends Application {
       //HERE DECLARE YOUR VARIABLE
       public static int MY_INT=1;

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       SharedPreference sf= ....;
       MY_INT=sf.getInt("MYDATA",0);
   }

   public static void setNewVariableToMyObject(int newdata){
      MY_INT=newdata;
      SharedPreference sf= ....
      sf.edit().putInt("MYDATA",MY_INT).commit();
   }
}
```

Whenever you want to change your variable use this function. You are also sure that whenever your application become created, your variable would be assigned by the last saved Var.

Comment: So I should read from preferences in onCreate() and write to preferences in onPause()?

Comment: There is no need to any sharedPreference or any on create or on pause method !!! just use that static variable like this MasterApplciation.MY_INT=7. @BhargavKumarR

Comment: No.. I want to persist this static member into shared preferences before android kills my app.

Comment: I dont want to persist static member for every change. I want it to happen only when android removes my app from memory.

Comment: so Just use that function in your onPause method of your activities.
The better approach is to just put it in onDestroy of your main Activity, the activity which always in backstack. when the android remove your app, OnDestroy would be called and the data would be saved in shared preference. @BhargavKumarR

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a function be executed when whatever Activity is on paused you can create a class that extends Application, and there implement onPause() method with your logic. 
If you need more help or need some more information about how SharedPreferences class works let me know!!!